# Playing a sound in a ipython notebook

Tags: audio, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to be able to play a sound file in a ipython notebook.
My aim is to be able to listen to the results of different treatments applied to a sound directly from within the notebook.
Is this possible? If yes, what is the best solution to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A small example that might be relevant : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5507501/the%20sound%20of%20hydrogen.ipynb

it should be possible to avoid gooing through external files by base64 encoding as for PNG/jpg...

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I don't manage using external files. (despite changing path, I get WARNING:root:404 GET /files/440.wav (127.0.0.1) ). I'll have a look at how to avoid the use of external file.

Comment: Hum, weird, have you change CWD ? when you run the notebook, is the 440.wav file created ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was using an old version of ipython.
Everything works great now. Having player directly in notebook is very neat to play around with sounds

Comment: Btw, I updated (a few hours ago) to avoid going through the file system : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/07-the-sound-of-hydrogen.ipynb happy coincidence :-)

Comment: @Matt: why do you need to reimplement _scipy.io.wavfile.write_? It accepts   string buffer already... I.e. `buffer = StringIO.StringIO();wavfile.write(buffer, sample_rate, samples)`

Answer (score 100):

The previous answer is pretty old. You can use [IPython.display.Audio](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Audio) now. Like this:

```
import IPython
IPython.display.Audio("my_audio_file.mp3")
```

Note that you can also process any type of audio content, and pass it to this function as a `numpy` array.

If you want to display multiple audio files, use the following:

```
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio("my_audio_file.mp3"))
IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio("my_audio_file.mp3"))
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you want the sound to actually play automatically, then add the `autoplay=True` parameter. Like this: `IPython.display.Audio("my_audio_file.mp3", autoplay=True)`

Answer (score 4):

The code:

```
import IPython

IPython.display.Audio("my_audio_file.mp3")
```

may give an error of "Invalid Source" in IE11, try in other browsers it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the sound you are looking for could be also a "Text-to-Speech", I would like to mention that every time a start some long process in the background, I queue the execution of a cell like this too:

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output, display, HTML, Javascript

display(Javascript("""
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.text = "Process completed!";
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
"""))
```

You can change the text you want to hear with `msg.text`.

Answer (score 0):

The other available answers added an HTML element which I disliked, so I created the [`ringbell`](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/ringbell), which gets you both play a custom sound as such:

```
from ringbell import RingBell
RingBell(
    sample = "path/to/sample.wav",
    minimum_execution_time = 0,
    verbose = True
)
```

and it also gets you a one-lines to play a bell when a cell execution takes more than 1 minute (or a custom amount of time for that matter) or is fails with an exception:

```py
import ringbell.auto
```

You can install [this package from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ringbell/):

```bash
pip install ringbell
```